# How to solve $\Delta f + |f|^{4/(N-2)}f=0$?

Tags: analysis, proof-verification, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Let $f(x)= (1+ \frac{|x|^2}{N(N-2)})^{\frac{N-2}{2}}, (x\in \mathbb R^N).$

> My Question is: How to show that $\Delta f + |f|^{4/(N-2)}f=0$?

My attempt: Suppose take $N=3.$  Note that $\frac{\partial f (x)}{\partial x_1}= -\frac{1}{N}(1+ \frac{|x|^2}{N(N-2)})^{\frac{-N}{2}} x_1$ $x=(x_1, x_2, x_3)\in \mathbb R^3.$ So $$\frac{\partial^2 f (x)}{\partial x_1^2}= -\frac{1}{N}(1+ \frac{|x|^2}{N(N-2)})^{\frac{-N}{2}} + (1+ \frac{|x|^2}{N(N-2)})^{\frac{-N-2}{2}}  \frac{1}{N(N-2)} x_1^2$$ Hence,
$$\Delta f (x) = -\frac{3}{N}(1+ \frac{|x|^2}{N(N-2)})^{\frac{-N}{2}} + (1+ \frac{|x|^2}{N(N-2)})^{\frac{-N-2}{2}}  \frac{1}{N(N-2)} |x|^2$$

Comment: Note that the $N$ in the formula for $f$ is the same as the $N$ in the dimension of the space, so the $3$ in the last formula should be a $N$ (or all $N$'s should be $3$'s). Besides that, your calculation looks fine. You just need to collect the terms and then the given formula will pop up.